# Typescript foreach variable not available

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, typescript

I have a foreach loop where I create a new temp array, then run a nested foreach loop. I'm then trying to access the temp array inside the nested foreach loop, but it's coming back with a "variable not available" error.

```
let final = {
    array: []
};

myArray.forEach(item =>
{
    let newObject = { items: [] };

    item.subArray.forEach(subItem =>
    {
        var subObject = { prop: subItem.prop };

        // Error here: "newObject is not available"
        newObject.items.push(subObject);
    });

    // Error here: "final is not available"
    final.array.push(newObject);
});
```

I know I can provide `this` to the array by providing it as an argument (eg: `item.subArray.forEach(subItem => {},`**`this`**`);`)

but this doesn't help me because tempArray doesn't exist at the class level.

I have the same problem when I try to assign my temp array to the "final" array declared outside the foreach.

Is there a way I can access the parent scope from within the foreach?

*I should point out this code exists within a function defined on a class. I'm basically trying to aggregate properties with a certain value from within the subarray*

Screenshot showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hawoz.png
(The code visible in the image is within the first `forEach` loop)

---

**Update**: I figured this out, it was an issue between using `let` and `var`. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I finally figured this out. In my actual code I was creating `newObject` using TypeScript's `let` keyword. I changed it to `var` instead and it started working.

Chalk that up to me not understanding the difference between `let` (block scope) and `var` (global scope) - d'oh!

The solution listed below also worked for me, but simply changing `let` to `var` has meant that my original code works perfectly.

---

I solved this by using `map()` instead of `forEach()`:

```
var final = {
    array: []
};

var finalArray = myArray.map(function (item)
{
    let newObject = { items: [] };

    var tempArray = item.subArray.map(function (subItem)
    {
        var subObject = { prop: subItem.prop };
        return subObject;
    });

    newObject.items = tempArray;

    return newObject;
});

final.array = finalArray;
```

Comment: this doesnt do the same thing the first would. the code in your post would only store the last mapping.

Comment: @TamasHegedus Yes, fair point. I actually used the wrong code in the question, I'll update them both

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted into the question must not be your real code. if it was you would have had no problem accessing finalArray.

The results of both your snippets are very different.

the first will give you an array of all the properties of the sub item of the last item.

the seconds will give you an array of arrays where each array contains the properties of the sub item

If I understand correctly what you want is to get a single array containing all the properties of all the sub items. so you want to map each item to an array of sub-item properties and then flatten the result into a single array.

How about this?

```
var items = [
    {subitems:[
        {prop:1},
        {prop:2},
    ]},
        {subitems:[
        {prop:3},
        {prop:4},
    ]},
]

var result = items.map(function(item){
    return item.subitems.map(function(subitem){
        return subitem.prop;
    })
}).reduce(function(prev,curr){
    return prev.concat(curr);
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You are correct, the code is a simplified version of my actual code. In my actual code, I iterate through an array and build up a new object for each item in the subarray and add it to a new array. I simply cannot understand why I cannot access the `tempArray` variable inside the foreach - I assumed it was a quirk of TypeScript

Comment: ok, so you have two questions here, one is about variable scope, and for that I need a larget picture to see why the finalArray is out of scope. The second is how to map and then flatten. which I think I answered.

Comment: Sorry, I worded it badly - the variable scope issue is my only problem here :) I've updated my question to be more accurate to my use case. Here's a screenshot *(sorry!)* showing the issue http://i.imgur.com/HWCz0Ed.png The code you can see there is within the first `forEach` loop.

Comment: I recreated something similar to your screenshot. and it works, even with the keyword let(as it should). what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript version 1.8.9

Comment: Then unless the screenshot is hiding some detail I have no idea why it does not work for you. let makes the variable block scoped, you are using it inside the block where you declared it. it's inside a deeper block but that should not matter.

Comment: Yeah, it's strange. I might try properly reproducing this at some point, but for now using `var` solved my problem.